# Excel Pivot move result row to first row

Tags: excel, pivot

I am primarly a programmer and dont work often with Excel, but no I have to build a Report. I guess this is a very easy Problem or not possible at all, but i could find nothing by myself

I made a Pivotreport, and now I want to move the Overall-Sum to the front of the Report, so that if somebody reads it, he sees the overallnumbers first.

I only have a german Excel, so I dont know the english names here, I hope the screenshot makes it clear:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do using `Slicers`, running two pivot tables, and hiding unnecessary columns.

I built a sample table to work with that can be applied to your data:

[image: pivot1]

Select your pivot table to open the `Pivottable Tools` menu, then click on "Insert Slicer":

[image: pivot2]

Select the fields you would like to be able to filter:

[image: pivot3]

Copy and paste your entire pivot table into a new sheet.  Ensure it remains a pivot table when you paste it.

In the newly copied pivot table, remove all columns so that you have just Row Labels and Grand Totals remaining:

[image: pivot4]

Return to the original pivot table and insert three columns to the left of the pivot table:

[image: pivotcolumns]

Navigate back to the copy of your pivot table and copy this trimmed down pivot table:

[image: pivottrimmed]

Return to the original pivot table and paste it into the range to the left of the pivot table (leaving a blank column in between):

[image: pivotpaste]

Hide the `Row Labels` on the pivot table on the right side, shrink the blank column between the two pivot tables, and rearrange your `slicers`:

[image: slicers]

You now have the Grand Total at the beginning of the pivot table and it can be filtered via the `slicers`.

Comment: Thank you, i hoped there would be a simpler solution, but i guess i have to do it that way...